# PowerShell: Sorting a Customized pscustomobject

Tags: xml, powershell, sorting

i am working on a small application, which gets relevant data from an xml, converts it and finally outputs it as html. Reading my data works, but i still have to sort it.
The sorting has to be done in three steps. I hope you can express it like this.

```
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {

$Content = [xml](Get-Content -Path $file.FullName)

$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($Content.NameTable)
$ns=@{XXY="http://br-automation.co.at/AS/VC/Project"}

$AlarmgroupIndex = Select-Xml -Xml $Content -XPath "//XXY:Property[contains(@Name,'Index')]" -namespace $ns | select -ExpandProperty node
$AlarmgroupIndexString = $AlarmgroupIndex.Value
$AlarmgroupLanguageText = Select-Xml -Xml $Content -XPath "//XXY:TextLayer" -namespace $ns | select -ExpandProperty node
$AlarmgroupIndexMap = Select-Xml -Xml $Content -XPath "//XXY:Index" -namespace $ns | select -ExpandProperty node

$LUT =@{}  
$AlarmgroupIndexMap | foreach{
    $LUT.($_.ID) = $_.Value
}

$tmpArray =@() 
$list = $AlarmgroupLanguageText | foreach{ 

   $LanguageIDString = $_.LanguageId
    
        
        $AlarmgroupTextLayer = Select-Xml -Xml $Content -XPath "//XXY:TextLayer[@LanguageId='$LanguageIDString']/XXY:Text" -namespace $ns | select -ExpandProperty node 

        $AlarmgroupTextLayer | foreach{  

            if($LUT.ContainsKey($_.ID))
            {
                $ID_string = $LUT[$_.ID]
            }
            
            #$tmpArray  += $AlarmgroupIndexString + ";" + $LanguageIDString + ";" + $ID_string  + ";" + $_.Value 
            
            [pscustomobject]@{
                GroupID = $AlarmgroupIndexString
                Language = $LanguageIDString
                TextID = $ID_string
                Text = $_.Value
            }


        }

    $LanguageIDString=""
    
}
```

I tried to sort the $List as following (btw. with the same result)

```
$list | Sort-Object -Property Language, GroupID, TextID
#$list |Sort-Object {$_.Language,$_.GrouID, $_.TextID -as [int]}
```

Sorting by TextID in the last step does not work.

1       en       50     texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
1       en       39     texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
1       en       34     texttexttexttexttexttext
1       en       49     texttexttexttext
1       en       54     texttext

Does anybody has a idea how i can solve this?

The target must be a sorted list, whose rows and columns I can read out individually and use to form a string from the relevant data
TIA

Comment: Not sure what your desired output would be, but if you add the TextID property in as int as in `TextID = [int]$ID_string`, then `$list | Sort-Object GroupID, Language, TextID` would probably get you what you want?

Comment: If you want to keep the `TextID` property values as `[string]` but make `Sort-Object`'s comparison logic treat it as `[int]` you want `... |Sort-Object Language, GroupID, {$_.TextID -as [int]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `Sort-Object` to treat an individual sort key as a different type you'll want to supply a scriptblock *in place of that specific property key*:

```bsh
$list |Sort-Object Language, GroupID, {$_.TextID -as [int]}
```

If `TextID` should *always* be treated as an integer, you'll want to make that conversion when instantiating the object instead:

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    GroupID = $AlarmgroupIndexString
    Language = $LanguageIDString
    TextID = $ID_string -as [int] # convert value to [int] before assigning
    Text = $_.Value
}
```

Now `Sort-Object -Property TextID` will work as expected because an integer comparison will be made during sorting

---

For completeness, I should mention that **`Sort-Object` does not modify the input collection** - it just outputs the individual input elements in sequence based on the calculated sort order.

If you want to persist the re-ordering in your `$list` variable you need to overwrite it:

```
$list = $list |Sort-Object Language, GroupID, {$_.TextID -as [int]}

# list will now have retained the sort order from the previous pipeline
$list |Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: THX for your help. The created output file shows still the wrong order. e.g. 56,60,59,57,61  (formatedl ike the one in the question part)

Comment: @s0Nic just to be clear - `$list |Sort-Object` doesn't _modify_ the input collection - you need to re-assign the value, ie. `$list = $list |Sort-Object`